# Python opencv cv2.isOpened returns true but cam.grab()/cam.read() is unable to read frame

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi4

Camera module waveshare OV9281-110 monochrome camera (https://robu.in/product/waveshare-ov9281-110-mono-camera-for-raspberry-pi-global-shutter-1mp/)

I am working with raspberry-pi model 4-B with latest bullseye OS.

I am able to capture image using **libcamera-still -o test.png** command but when I try to read an image with opencv it returns None.
The output for cam.isOpened() is true but cam.grab() and cam.read() return false and (flase,None) respectively.

Code:

```
import cv2
cam_port = 0
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_port)
print(cv2.__version__)
print(cam.isOpened())
print(cam.grab())
print(cam.read())
cam.release()
```

Output:

```
4.5.5
True
False
(False, None)
```

I would appreciate a way to fix this or even just a way to find why the image is not being read/grabbed.

Note: I have read other questions with same heading but those solutions did not work out for me. and I was able to read image when I was working with raspberry pi camera 1.3 but unable to read with this new camera.

camera-info

```
~ $ v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --all
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : unicam
    Card type        : unicam
    Bus info         : platform:fe801000.csi
    Driver version   : 5.15.56
    Capabilities     : 0xa5a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x25200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : unicam
    Model            : unicam
    Serial           : 
    Bus info         : platform:fe801000.csi
    Media version    : 5.15.56
    Hardware revision: 0x00000000 (0)
    Driver version   : 5.15.56
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000005
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000003 (3)
    Name             : unicam-image
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags         : default
    Pad 0x01000004   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000007: from remote pad 0x1000002 of entity 'ov9281 10-0060': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (unicam-image: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 1920
    Size Image        : 921600
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : sRGB
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
    Quantization      : Full Range
    Flags
```

Comment: does that thing have a V4L driver, i.e. can you get a video feed using ffmpeg or vlc or guvcview or something like that?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz No, I am unable to get video feed at the moment with either of those module.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the device is supposed to support video feed, I am not sure if I am missing some libraries on my device or if the module driver is corrupted.

Comment: dtoverlay=ov9281

Comment: ls /boot/overlays/ov9281.dtbo

Comment: Didn't you added dtoverlay?

Comment: @toyotaSupra "dtoverlay=ov9281" already set in /boot/config.txt

Comment: Here is link. https://www.arducam.com/docs/pi/ov9281/tutorial/ and this too https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/OV9281-110_Camera

Comment: @toyotaSupra followed all the steps on arducam.com website and waveshare as well the test passes but there is no video feed using "./yavta --capture=1000 -n 3 --encode-to=file.h264 -f UYVY -m -T /dev/video0"(Unable to start streaming: Invalid argument (22)) or other video player.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I am able to capture image when using raspberry pi in headless mode but fails when there is a display available. Tried to display video feed using VLC, ffmpeg, guvview and few more

Comment: https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/migrated/ov9281-1mp-global-shutter-raspberrypi-camera/

Comment: I will let u know.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I am able to see video using --qt-preview flag but it doesn't work without it

Comment: Oh! btw. I'm, sorry. I don't used qt.

Comment: @toyotaSupra dont be sorry, your help and time is appreciated

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it does have a V4L driver, sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I got a video feed using libcamera